# Magento, how to change home page?

Tags: magento

I see that you can set a cms home page at "Default Pages" at admin panel (system/configuration/web) but I want a whole template including [html][head][body] tags to be shown, is this possible?

I can't do it via (CMS/Pages) as it deletes/modifies the code.. Even when I set it on "empty" don't really understand it..

Help would be much appreciated, cheers!

Comment: Here solution: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-to-change-the-home-page

Answer (score 0):

The file that you want is the layout file. If you need to add new layout of your home page then you can make a new layout file using following link

http://rakeshwebdev.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/add-new-custom-page-layout-in-magento-1-7/

Then after making layout while creating CMS Page go to layout section and choose your created layout. Then your home page will have what you want.

> Note: By default header, footer all these are kept in different file and called from the 1column.phtml etc. So it will be always better to keep it that way only. As we always should follow Magento programming methodology.